# How to move the "Read more" button to the end of the post at this WordPress theme?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I downloaded this theme and when you add the "more" tag in WordPress, it adds the "read more" button at the bottom along Tweet , Like and Comments buttons.

a) I'd like the ability to show the "read more" in its classic form after the post excerpt in form of a link.

b) Then the "comments" icon to be moved near the Tweet and Like buttons.

I've zero knowledge on CSS/HTML and would be immensely thankful to the person who could help.

The files:

Visual Instructions ------> http://bit.ly/WKdMCl

Theme in zip format ------> http://bit.ly/UovMlW

Real demonstration of theme in action ----> http://bit.ly/HtSIxn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to edit theme core files in order to achieve **a** and **b**. I tried something on firebug for your ease. Check the image: http://tinypic.com/r/2jdqds8/6

If you want something like then you just have to edit one single file, that is *style.css*

Follow the simple instructions below:

1. Open *style.css* located in template directory with Netbeans IDE, Notepad++ or WordPad.
2. Search the code *".post-meta .readmore"* (without quotes) and replace it with below code snippet:

   `.post-meta .readmore {border: 0;padding: 2px 0 10px 12px;margin:0;}`
3. Search the code *".post-meta .readmore a"* (without quotes) and replace it with below code snippet:
   `.post-meta .readmore a {color: #317CC8;display: block;line-height: 15px;padding-left:20px;position: relative;text-decoration: underline;top: -30px;}`
4. Search the code *".post-meta .comments"* (without quotes) and replace it with below code snippet:
   `.post-meta .comments { margin: 3px 0 0 16px; padding: 0 16px 3px 20px; color: #c9c9c9; font-size: 10px;  float:left;  font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase; background: url("images/comments.png") no-repeat left 3px; border:none; }`

I'm sure this will achieve what is demonstrated in image(attached as link).

Comment: One question Aky... Is it possible to move the "Read more..." at the end of the text?

Comment: Yeah, it is very much possible. But you will have to play with PHP code. You can play with it on a test server.

Answer (score 1):

b) Remove `float:right;` from the css `.post-meta .comments { }` in the `style.css` file.